# graylog's logs show ERROR information: ... cause io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: syscall:read(..) failed: Connection reset by peer)

Tags: graylog2, connection-reset

I use graylog to collect message, and i have a problem that graylog's logs show so many same `ERROR` messages like this :

```
2019-10-24 02:01:38,731 ERROR: org.graylog2.plugin.inputs.transports.AbstractTcpTransport - Error in Input [GELF TCP/[MessageInput id]] (channel [id: 0x345b69f0, L:/[ip]:[port] ! R:/[ip]:[port]]) (cause io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: syscall:read(..) failed: Connection reset by peer)
```

I have tried to change the configuration information for Input:

1.change the `Maximum Message Size` to 1MB.
2.change the `Receive Buffer Size` .(I set the Receive Buffer Size 1MB,but graylogs log show:

```
2019-10-24 02:01:57,085 WARN : org.graylog2.plugin.inputs.transports.AbstractTcpTransport - receiveBufferSize (SO_RCVBUF) for input GELFTCPInput{title=numessage-prod-logs, type=org.graylog2.inputs.gelf.tcp.GELFTCPInput, nodeId=c72e023a-ad91-4a38-98c8-e2f927ae4faa} (channel [id: 0x0682df83, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:12201]) should be 1048576 but is 425984.)
```

I run graylog server in docker and I can't find the `R's ip:port` from my cluster.

I have not solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I check that R:ip port and find it is the loaderbalance.And this Error message will not make the log lose, so im find.

Answer (score 0):

I'll asnwer the question over in the Graylog community as negotiate a problem in different locations by the same person is not quite the best:

https://community.graylog.org/t/graylogs-logs-show-error-information-cause-io-netty-channel-unix-errors-nativeioexception-syscall-read-failed-connection-reset-by-peer/12504